# Free auto screen recorder for windows that runs on background

Tags: windows, gratis, screen-recording

I want a free screen recorder app that starts recording when Windows starts up, and records the entire activity of the user since the computer turns on, and in a way that runs in background without annoying the user. The reason for this is that my client is doing some weird stuff to windows and i need to see what he is doing. Thanks.

Comment: How much time are you looking to record? Is it alright if the resulting video file is huge?. And what kind of weird stuff is he doing? Wouldn't an event log or a key logger do the job?

Comment: I plan to record an entire day... well maybe you're right, i think the file size would be huge... Maybe a keylogger will work even better... do you have any recommendations?

Comment: A quick online search should give you plenty of examples. It's also not difficult to write your own. But make sure to ask the client's permission first because having or using a keylogger on someone else's computer is illegal in many jurisdictions. I have no experience with keyloggers so I'm not qualified to post an answer recommending one or the other.

Comment: I don't think you should be recording a clients screen, i have no idea if it's legal, but I doubt it is. If you ask him, he'll probably just tell you, rather than letting you record his screen...